# Observing a LiveData does not trigger after the second change in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using viewModel to pass data to my compose view. The thing is I wanna handle expand and collapse view by filed inside my models in viewModel. So If some UI click on expand method I will call viewModel and doExpand method like this:

```
 private val _acquiredCoupons = MutableLiveData<List<AcquiredCoupon>>(listOf())
 val acquiredCoupons: LiveData<List<AcquiredCoupon>> = _acquiredCoupons

    fun doExpand(coupon : AcquiredCoupon){
        
        val index = _acquiredCoupons.value?.indexOf(coupon) ?: -1
         val newItems = _acquiredCoupons.value?.toMutableList().also {
            it?.get(index)?.isExpanded = true
        }
        _acquiredCoupons.value = newItems
        Timber.i("Mahdi $index")
    }
```

But the thing is after update models in compose UI will not trigger and re compose is not happening!
I'm observing the live data like this:

```
val items = viewModel.acquiredCoupons.observeAsState(initial = emptyList())
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're observing the livedata?

Comment: Make sure you are using `by` and not `=`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @ImMathan I solved it with putting new stateFlow and just observe it without any action, and every time I update expanded status, also update that value. It was only trick worked for me.

Comment: Can you share the solution? thanks

Comment: @PabloMartinez StateFlow was not good solution here cause I wanna share stream of data that should change, so my final solution was update an item in whole list and then replace whole list with new that involve updated one, then live data will trigger!

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is still having this issue observing a list, I found a good solution was to switch from `List` to [SnapshotStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList) in the ViewModel/LiveData.

After converting from this:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val itemLiveData: LiveData<List<String>>
        get() = items

    private val items = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    private val itemImpl = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun addItem(name: String){
        itemImpl.add(name)
        items.postValue(itemImpl)
    }
}
```

To this form:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val itemLiveData: LiveData<SnapshotStateList<String>>
        get() = items

    private val items = MutableLiveData<SnapshotStateList<String>>()
    private val itemImpl = mutableStateListOf<String>()

    fun addItem(name: String){
        itemImpl.add(name)
        items.postValue(itemImpl)
    }
}
```

My composable worked as expected with when items were added to the list

```
@Composable
fun ItemList(model: MainViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Column {
        Button( 
            onClick = { model.addItem("New item") },
            content = { Text(text="Add item") } 
        )
                
        val items by model.itemLiveData.observeAsState()

        if( items.isNullOrEmpty() ) {
            Text(text = "No items")
        }
        else {
            items?.forEach { item ->
                Text(text=item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `SnapshotStateList` and why is it important?  Suppose I just want to emit Strings, not a List?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky A `SnapshotStateList` detects mutations to the existing list (e.g. add or modify items in the list without making a "new" list). If you just want to emit strings, you don't need it, just emit a new string and state changes will be detected just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your observing code, you need to use `observeAsState`, so your view will be recomposed with any LiveData updates that changes the value.

`val items by viewModel.acquiredCoupons.observeAsState()`

Comment: Yes I'm using this but after update any value inside data change is not trigger!

Comment: Can you post the code where you are observing this live data?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you're passing the raw value to the `Composable` (please include a sample snippet to your question when you get a chance). If the value is considered equal to the previous value, a recomposition will not happen.

One way you can get around this is by passing the `State` object itself to the target `Composable`.

So for example if you were setup like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CouponBar(
    coupons: List<Coupon>
) { ... }
```

then try

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CouponBar(
    coupons: State<List<Coupon>>
) { ... }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it's: `import androidx.compose.runtime.State`

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you are using **list** instead of **MutableList** in your liveData.