# Jetpack Compose update UI MutableLiveData<ArrayList<>>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple ViewModel which holds a list of Todo objects.

```
class TodoListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _todoItems = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Todo>>()
    val todoItems: LiveData<ArrayList<Todo>> = _todoItems

    init {
        this.addTodo("Task 1")
        this.addTodo("Task 2")
        this.addTodo("Task 3")
    }

    fun addTodo(title: String){
        val items = _todoItems.value ?: arrayListOf<Todo>()
        items.add(Todo(1, title, "", false))
        _todoItems.value = items
    }
}
```

Inside the activity I want to show all the todos in a list. This already works, but when calling the function addTodo() (after render) the UI does not update.

```
class TodoListActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val todoListViewModel: TodoListViewModel = TodoListViewModel();

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            TodoApp {
                Surface {
                    Column {
                        TodoList(todoListViewModel)
                        AddTodoItem(todoListViewModel)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoList(todoListViewModel: TodoListViewModel) {
    val todoItems = todoListViewModel.todoItems.observeAsState()

    Column {
        todoItems.value?.forEach { item ->
            TodoItem(todo = item)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AddTodoItem(todoListViewModel: TodoListViewModel){
    Button(
        onClick = { todoListViewModel.addTodo("New Task") }
    ){
        Text(text = "Create a new Task")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoItem(todo: Todo) {
    Card {
        Column {
            Text(text = todo.title)
            Text(text = todo.description)
        }
    }
}
```

I also debugged inside the addTodo function. It seems fine so far. The new item is created and also gets added to the _todoItems list. I searched now alot, but cant find my mistake why the UI wont update when clicking the button to add a new item.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382335/android-jetpack-compose-observe-a-live-data-not-trigger-after-second-channge/69951257#69951257) help?

Comment: @TylerV with a SnapShotStateList it works. I thought it gonna work also with an ArrayList because I only found tutorials with that. But maybe it wont trigger the composable to be updated after the first rendering.

Comment: It works the first time because it's a new list, but when you add a new item to the existing list that change doesn't trigger the UI to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutableStateListOf()`:

```kotlin
    val todoItems = mutableStateListOf<Todo>()
```

This should solve your issue.

However, it is good practice to avoid using compose state in ViewModel. You can use `StateFlow` instead.

Create a `UiState` data class:

```kotlin
data class UiState(
    val todoItems: ArrayList<Todo> = ArrayList()
)
```

In your ViewModel:

```kotlin
    private val todoItems = ArrayList<Todo>()

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todoItems.add(todo)
        _uiState.update { it.copy(todoItems = todoItems) }
    }
```

In your Composable:

```kotlin
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
```